# Android Auto fails to start on the car monitor

Tags: usb, android-auto

I have a Samsung Galaxy Android Phone which runs on Android 10, One UI Version 2.0. It is an AT&T phone. I also have a Subaru Crosstrek.

The phone connected to the car thru Bluetooth and it does react to phone calls and texts without any issues through the Android Auto. All other applications work fine.

However, when I tried to connect the phone with the USB wire, the Android Auto application is not available on the car dashboard.

- I tried to connect a different phone - works correctly.
- I tried to put the SIM card from my phone to some other phone - works correctly.
- I also tried to re-install Android Auto and re-pair the phone with the car - still USB connection doesn't work
- I also consulted with Subaru. They exchanged the radio. It helped for a while and then it stopped working again.

When the phone does not connect through the USB, just Bluetooth - Android Auto does start on the phone and establishes the connection to the car. Then everything works fine.

Basically, I am connecting the phone with the USB and the button to the dashboard does not become enabled.

Any idea how to fix it?